# How do I test the user name in android

Tags: android

i finally figured out where to find most of this.

but now i need to know how to test one part of this program for a username.

My goal is if the user doesn't put anything in the program then don't allow anything to continue.

This is a big app. I have like 3 layout files and 3 java files. 
Any help would be good if you need me to send the file i can.

```
package edu.jones.demogamestartarrayadaptor;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameControlMainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    //Class-wide variables for data passed/returned
    private String userName = "";
    //Use an int for gameLevel,naturally...but, this requires
    //use of various methods to convert to String and back!
    private int gameLevel = 1;
    private EditText nameEntryET;
    private TextView gameLevelAnnouncerTV;
    private TextView gameLevelTV;
    Button doneButton;
    //This TV prompts user to enter name in the EditText
    //Then, it is made invisible
    private TextView namePromptTV;
    //These two start out invisible and then show the name
    private TextView nameSetTV;
    private TextView nameEntTV;

    //Array of choices for user
    static final String[] CHOICES = new String[]
    {
        "Read directions",
        "Play Game",
        "Quit"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Set up View ids
        nameEntryET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_nameET);
        gameLevelAnnouncerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_level_announcer_TV);
        gameLevelTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_level_TV);

        //Set the game level in the TextView
        gameLevelTV.setText(Integer.toString(gameLevel));
        namePromptTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_prompt_tv);
        nameSetTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_set_tv);
        nameEntTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_entered_tv);

        //Set Done button listener to get user's name
        doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        setDoneButtonListener();

        //Set up ArrayAdaptor for the options
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CHOICES));
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //Set up the listener for user clicks on the list
        setListClickListener();

        //this toast is for when it opens
        Toast.makeText(this, "yo whats up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }//END onCreate


    private void setDoneButtonListener()
    {
        doneButton.setOnClickListener
        (
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //Get user's name when button is clicked
                    //Call method to set text and hide button
                    setUserNameAndHideButton();
                }
            }
        );//END setOnClickListener
    }//END setDoneButtonListener

    //Sets up username in its TextView, and game level Views,
    //then hides the other Views & button
    private void setUserNameAndHideButton()
    {

        userName = nameEntryET.getText().toString();
        doneButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Your name has been entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //After getting the input, hide the EditText
        //VISIBLE(0), INVISIBLE(4) or GONE(8)
        nameEntryET.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        namePromptTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        nameEntTV.setText(userName);
        nameSetTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        nameEntTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gameLevelAnnouncerTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gameLevelTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }//END setUserNameAndHideButton

    //Set up the listener for the ListView to interpret user clicks
    private void setListClickListener()
    {
        //Set up the click listener for the options
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener
        (
            new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                //@Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                {
                    switch(arg2)
                    {
                        case 0: launchDirectionsPage();
                                break;
                        case 1: startGame();
                                break;
                        case 2: finish();
                                break;
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
            }//END OnItemClickListener
        );//END setOnItemClickListener
    }//END setListClickListener

    //Launch a simple activity to show a scroll view of directions
    protected void launchDirectionsPage()
    {
        //Set up Intent
        Intent launchDirections = new Intent(this, DirectionsPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(launchDirections);

    }//END launchDirectionsPage

    //Launch the activity that allows user to input new game value
    //Upon return the onActivityResult method is called
    protected void startGame()
    {

        //Set up Intent to launch other activity:  PlayGame
        Intent launchGame = new Intent(this, PlayGameActivity.class);
        //Info added to the Intent's Bundle to pass to PlayGameActivity
        launchGame.putExtra("bdl_username", userName);
        launchGame.putExtra("bdl_gamelevel", gameLevel);
        startActivityForResult(launchGame, 0);

    }//END startGame

    //This method will be called when the startGame activity terminates
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            //Reset the views to possibly updated info returned in the Intent

            //First, access the Bundle's values
            userName = data.getExtras().getString("bdl_returnUserName");
            gameLevel = data.getExtras().getInt("bdl_returnGameLevel");

            //Update the user name & game level with values from other activity
            nameEntTV.setText(userName);
            gameLevelTV.setText(Integer.toString(gameLevel));

        }
    }//END onActivityResult

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        //Add the username and game level to the Bundle
        outState.putString("bdl_savedusername", userName);
        outState.putInt("bdl_savedgamelevel", gameLevel);

    }//END onSaveInstanceState

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        //Restore the username and game level from the Bundle
        userName = savedInstanceState.getString("bdl_savedusername");
        gameLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt("bdl_savedgamelevel");

    }//END onRestoreInstanceState

}//END GameControlMainActivity
```

Comment: TLDR, please edit and post minimal code explaining your problem

Comment: Are you basically just asking how to test if the username `EditText` is empty?

Comment: "This is a big app. I have like 3 layout files and 3 java files." i loled.. anyway on editText where user can enter username you can check if it has focus or not. If focus is not on editText or input is empty then disable everything else I dont know what other things you have

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic : Yeah, I resisted the urge to comment - I'm not even sure how many files I've got in my current project.

Comment: @Squonk It's always funny to visit SO :) However Hank, I dont mean anything in bad way, it was just funny :)

Comment: i am really bad at coding. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking to stop if the username is not entered,  just do this:

```
private void setDoneButtonListener()
{
    doneButton.setOnClickListener
    (
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                if (nameEntryET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //Get user's name when button is clicked
                    //Call method to set text and hide button
                    setUserNameAndHideButton();
                }
            }
        }
    );//END setOnClickListener
}//END setDoneButtonListener
```

if `nameEntryET` does not have a value entered, `nameEntryET.getText().toString()` will return an empty string.

Comment: very good worked very well thanks. the nameEnrtyET.getText().toString().equals("") 
I would have never thought of.